# Laravel Multiple WHERE() Operator Precedence

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I have the following query written using Eloquent:

```
Contact::select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`created_at`),'%b %d') as date"))
                                 ->addSelect(DB::raw("`created_at`"))
                                 ->addSelect(DB::raw("COUNT(*) as `count`"))
                                 ->where('created_at', '>', $date)
                                 ->ofType($type)
                                 ->groupBy('date')
                                 ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                                 ->lists('count', 'date');
```

You can see it uses a query scope method `ofType()` Here is that method, it just adds a bunch of extra where clauses to the query:

```
return $query->where('list_name', '=', 'Apples')
            ->orWhere('list_name', '=', 'Oranges')
            ->orWhere('list_name', '=', 'Pears')
            ->orWhere('list_name', '=', 'Plums')
            ->orWhere('list_name', '=', 'Blueberries');
```

Ultimately this results in the following real SQL query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`created_at`),'%b %d') as date,`created_at`, COUNT(*) as `count` 
FROM `contacts` 
WHERE `created_at` > '2014-10-02 00:00:00' 
AND `list_name` = 'Apples' 
OR `list_name` = 'Oranges' 
OR `list_name` = 'Pears' 
OR `list_name` = 'Plums' 
OR `list_name` = 'Blueberries' 
GROUP BY `date` 
ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
```

The problem is, the WHERE `created_at` > '2014-10-02 00:00:00' clause is being missed when the OR clauses kick in. Due to operator precendence. I need to wrap all the clauses after the first AND in parentheses, like so:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`created_at`),'%b %d') as date,`created_at`, COUNT(*) as `count` 
    FROM `contacts` 
    WHERE `created_at` > '2014-10-02 00:00:00' 
    AND 
   (`list_name` = 'Apples' 
    OR `list_name` = 'Oranges' 
    OR `list_name` = 'Pears' 
    OR `list_name` = 'Plums' 
    OR `list_name` = 'Blueberries')
    GROUP BY `date` 
    ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
```

So, my question is, how would I achieve this using the eloquent query builder. Thank you.

Comment: Did you looked for Advanced Wheres?  I think this might help you achieving your query: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to mOrsa I've figured it out, by changing my query scope method to take advantage of advanced where:

```
return $query->where(function($query){

          $query->orWhere('list_name', '=', 'Apples')
                ->orWhere('list_name', '=', 'Oranges')
                ->orWhere('list_name', '=', 'Pears')
                ->orWhere('list_name', '=', 'Plums')
                ->orWhere('list_name', '=', 'Blueberries');
        });
```

I get the desired SQL.